# Laravel supervisor stuck randomly

Tags: laravel, queue, supervisord

I am using Laravel supervisor for running job in background on AWS ec2 instance. It is using for very big files import to mysql and its randomly stuck the supervisor. There is no any logs in the log files. How can we check what cause this?

Answer (score 0):

When a job crashes and there is no log, in the `Laravel` storage folders. Most of the times this is due to the PHP environment crashing. This means that you should probably check where PHP store the [errors logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel), as when an out of memory exception happens, the process is dead and can't write to `Laravels` handler.

In have had this a couple of times, all of the times it is each process exceeding it's memory limits. When you talk about big files to import, this can quickly chug up a lot of memory, due to having creating objects with different kind of data. I believe this is the route you should go down and check.